# Google Beacon: Invalid AdvertisedId id bytes length

Tags: api, google-beacon-platform

I have just learned about google beacon and I am having trouble with the register.

Here is my Request Body

```
   {
  "advertisedId": {
    "type": "EDDYSTONE",
    "id": "f7826da6bc5b71e0893e753553354637"
  },
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "description": "An example beacon",
}
```

The result:

```
{
  "error": {
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", 
    "message": "Invalid AdvertisedId id bytes length", 
    "code": 400
  }
}
```

I have read some sources about this problem but I still cannot get it. Can someone please help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

For a custom namespace get first 8 character of beacon device id and last 
 12 character of  device id.

Eg. : 8B0CA750-E7A7-4E14-BD99-095477CB3E77 becomes 8B0CA750095477CB3E77